# amp-story-player doesn't load stories if they inserted later

Tags: amp-html

I want to get the stories from server first then create `<amp-story-player>` tag and insert `<a>` tags in it.
If I wait until the stories are fetched from server and then inserted to `<amp-story-player>`, the amp-story-player loader spins forever.
Can someone explain how to use amp-story-player in this case?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Amp Stories are so buggy. Definitely not stable.